# virtualenv: permission denied error even though i have symlink

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I'm using MacOS High Sierra.

I made a symlink to my virtualenv.py

`-rw-r--r--    1 myname  admin   99021  3  7 23:40 virtualenv.py`

As you can see it has READ permission already.

and now `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 myname  admin         91  3 21 22:51 virtualenv -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py`

I think there is no problem with these but I get permission denied error.

I think I won't know what I'll be doing and I'm afraid to fix these kind of things myself, so I need someone's help.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to have permission on the symlink **and** its target.

Answer (score 2):

`chmod -h 400 /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`
solved my question. on MacOS -h option can modify symlink permission.